# Cash Deposit to Other Person's account Sparkasse Germany

Tags: germany, deposits

I want to make a payment to a Sparkasse account in Germany. I am currently in Germany but do not have a bank account. 
Can I make this cash deposit directly from one of the Sparkasse branches?

Comment: Have you called the bank?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should be possible (though any given financial institution or branches thereof may chose not to provide this service). According to this [source](http://www.zahlungsmittel.org/banking/bargeld-auf-fremdes-konto/) the Sparkasse offers it (edit to add: per OP's comment the Sparkasse offers it only for accounts with the same local branch). It is called *Bareinzahlung auf fremdes Konto*. The process is done using a [*Zahlschein*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zahlschein). Obviously you will need the bank details (IBAN, BIC) of the benefited.

Note that special scrutinity concerning your identity may be applied to prevent money laundering - be prepared to identify yourself with ID or passport. There will also be additional fees higher than depositing to your own account (edit to add: per OP's comment the Deutsche Bank has a fee of 15 Euros per transaction).

[Source](http://www.zahlungsmittel.org/banking/bargeld-auf-fremdes-konto/)

Comment: Well I checked. Indeed it is possible by Sparkasse but from a branch in the same city. Not otherwise. Deutsche Bank, provides this service to any German account but there is a fee of 15 Euro for each transaction.

Comment: @ArnabAuddy, thanks for the input. Too bad, I had "issues" with Sparkasse and their localized branches too.

Comment: @ArnabAuddy The Sparlasse offerse the same service as well, but they as well take a fee.

Comment: There are ≈ 400 different regional Sparkassen in Germany which are actually independent banks. They are organized in associations and appear under very similar branding, though:  this can make it difficult to understand at the first glance *which* bank one is actually dealing with: It is not the same local branch that is required, but rather the same bank = regional Sparkasse. Roughly the same holds for Volksbanken/Raiffeisenbanken, BTW. Not so long ago, withdrawing at another than "your" regional Sparkasse would also cost a "withdrawal from other bank" fee. And as depositing cash money...

Comment: ... (or cheques) is *very* unusual nowadays, and due to anti money laundering laws, many banks do not provide this service any more. Not even all Sparkassen (Being public banks, they are sometimes required by law to provide particular services that private banks can choose to offer or not) I guess, cash deposits to third parties re not considered officially an important public service (any more) given that anyone who is legally staying in the EU has a right to get a basic banking account at any bank in Germany who offers banking accounts to private customers.